# Python: Read Json and create chart

Tags: python, json, pandas, matplotlib

I have a json file:

```
{
"code":"200000",
"data":[
    {
        "price":"1001",
        "sequence":"1636607335665",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"0.00000544",
        "time":1657828843154264094
    },
    {
        "price":"5538.9",
        "sequence":"1636607335668",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.00000098",
        "time":1657828843399526634
    },
    {
        "price":"1001",
        "sequence":"1636607335707",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"0.00000098",
        "time":1657828850316727168
    },
    {
        "price":"1001",
        "sequence":"1636607335710",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"0.00000098",
        "time":1657828850582673268
    },
    {
        "price":"1001",
        "sequence":"1636607335713",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"0.00000098",
        "time":1657828850924769384
    },
    {
        "price":"1001",
        "sequence":"1636607335716",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"0.00000098",
        "time":1657828850993197165
    },
    {
        "price":"1001",
        "sequence":"1636607335719",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"0.00000098",
        "time":1657828851193402610
    },
    {
        "price":"5538.9",
        "sequence":"1636607335722",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.00000089",
        "time":1657828857749638652
    },
    {
        "price":"1001",
        "sequence":"1636607335725",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"0.00000018",
        "time":1657828859913652722
    },
    {
        "price":"1001",
        "sequence":"1636607335728",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"0.00000018",
        "time":1657828860167682305
    },
    {
        "price":"1001",
        "sequence":"1636607335731",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"0.00000018",
        "time":1657828860325667720
    },
    {
        "price":"1001",
        "sequence":"1636607335734",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"0.00000018",
        "time":1657828860426539709
    },
    {
        "price":"1001",
        "sequence":"1636607335737",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"0.00000018",
        "time":1657828860605057780
    },
    {
        "price":"5538.9",
        "sequence":"1636607335740",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.00000016",
        "time":1657829347628544318
    },
    {
        "price":"1001",
        "sequence":"1636607335751",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"1",
        "time":1657830042459243431
    },
    {
        "price":"1001",
        "sequence":"1636607335754",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"1",
        "time":1657830042758958029
    },
    {
        "price":"1001",
        "sequence":"1636607335757",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"1",
        "time":1657830043035655903
    },
    {
        "price":"1001",
        "sequence":"1636607335760",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"1",
        "time":1657830043157218306
    },
    {
        "price":"1001",
        "sequence":"1636607335763",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"1",
        "time":1657830043346430450
    },
    {
        "price":"5538.9",
        "sequence":"1636607335766",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.16496021",
        "time":1657830098124334016
    },
    {
        "price":"18000",
        "sequence":"1636607335770",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.22673876",
        "time":1657830098399521206
    },
    {
        "price":"18000",
        "sequence":"1636607335773",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.00000023",
        "time":1657830098764936584
    },
    {
        "price":"1001",
        "sequence":"1636607335922",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"0.07833984",
        "time":1657830344363632786
    },
    {
        "price":"1001",
        "sequence":"1636607335925",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"0.07833984",
        "time":1657830344675019788
    },
    {
        "price":"1001",
        "sequence":"1636607335928",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"0.07833984",
        "time":1657830345026214909
    },
    {
        "price":"1001",
        "sequence":"1636607335931",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"0.07833984",
        "time":1657830345193678817
    },
    {
        "price":"1001",
        "sequence":"1636607335934",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"0.07833984",
        "time":1657830345382321251
    },
    {
        "price":"18000",
        "sequence":"1636607335937",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.02173928",
        "time":1657830368271317194
    },
    {
        "price":"18000",
        "sequence":"1636607335940",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.00000002",
        "time":1657830368537904561
    },
    {
        "price":"1001",
        "sequence":"1636607336107",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"0.00434786",
        "time":1657830506400266964
    },
    {
        "price":"1001",
        "sequence":"1636607336110",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"0.00434786",
        "time":1657830506678292287
    },
    {
        "price":"1001",
        "sequence":"1636607336113",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"0.00434786",
        "time":1657830506963452449
    },
    {
        "price":"1001",
        "sequence":"1636607336116",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"0.00434786",
        "time":1657830507262876484
    },
    {
        "price":"1001",
        "sequence":"1636607336119",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"0.00434786",
        "time":1657830507274604674
    },
    {
        "price":"18000",
        "sequence":"1636607336122",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.00120653",
        "time":1657830544353165335
    },
    {
        "price":"18000",
        "sequence":"1636607336125",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.00000001",
        "time":1657830544694561727
    },
    {
        "price":"18000",
        "sequence":"1636607336144",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.75031517",
        "time":1657831267172000485
    },
    {
        "price":"19000",
        "sequence":"1636607336146",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"1",
        "time":1657831267172000485
    },
    {
        "price":"19349",
        "sequence":"1636607336148",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.90156477",
        "time":1657831267172000485
    },
    {
        "price":"19349",
        "sequence":"1636607336153",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.00051682",
        "time":1657832244551197889
    },
    {
        "price":"19349",
        "sequence":"1636607336156",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.00051682",
        "time":1657832323552102950
    },
    {
        "price":"19349",
        "sequence":"1636607336159",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.00051682",
        "time":1657832404615114041
    },
    {
        "price":"19349",
        "sequence":"1636607336162",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.0002",
        "time":1657832453907261588
    },
    {
        "price":"19349",
        "sequence":"1636607336165",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.00051682",
        "time":1657832502167873450
    },
    {
        "price":"19349",
        "sequence":"1636607336178",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.00516822",
        "time":1657840322172772611
    },
    {
        "price":"19349",
        "sequence":"1636607336181",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.00516822",
        "time":1657841032582704012
    },
    {
        "price":"19349",
        "sequence":"1636607336188",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.49431546",
        "time":1657841056954765534
    },
    {
        "price":"19349",
        "sequence":"1636607336191",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.00516822",
        "time":1657841633410013927
    },
    {
        "price":"19343.1953",
        "sequence":"1636607336194",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"0.00025848",
        "time":1657841683315799309
    },
    {
        "price":"19349",
        "sequence":"1636607336202",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.00031009",
        "time":1657841883739588741
    },
    {
        "price":"19337.3923414",
        "sequence":"1636607336205",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"0.00025856",
        "time":1657841909289751556
    },
    {
        "price":"19343.19529998",
        "sequence":"1636607336213",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.00025856",
        "time":1657841956440581560
    },
    {
        "price":"19349",
        "sequence":"1636607336215",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.00005161",
        "time":1657841956440581560
    },
    {
        "price":"19337.39234139",
        "sequence":"1636607336220",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"0.00025863",
        "time":1657849200908617135
    },
    {
        "price":"19331.59112369",
        "sequence":"1636607336222",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"0.00000137",
        "time":1657849200908617135
    },
    {
        "price":"19343.19529997",
        "sequence":"1636607336227",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.00025863",
        "time":1657849228110938680
    },
    {
        "price":"19349",
        "sequence":"1636607336229",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.00005154",
        "time":1657849228110938680
    },
    {
        "price":"19337.39234138",
        "sequence":"1636607336234",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"0.0002587",
        "time":1657849268869709337
    },
    {
        "price":"19331.59112369",
        "sequence":"1636607336236",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"0.0000013",
        "time":1657849268869709337
    },
    {
        "price":"19343.19529996",
        "sequence":"1636607336241",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.0002587",
        "time":1657849326110758419
    },
    {
        "price":"19349",
        "sequence":"1636607336243",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.00005147",
        "time":1657849326110758419
    },
    {
        "price":"19349",
        "sequence":"1636607336248",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.00031009",
        "time":1657849345012661392
    },
    {
        "price":"19337.39234137",
        "sequence":"1636607339163",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"0.00025877",
        "time":1657867041820159833
    },
    {
        "price":"19331.59112369",
        "sequence":"1636607339165",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"0.00025597",
        "time":1657867041820159833
    },
    {
        "price":"5689",
        "sequence":"1636607339562",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.01",
        "time":1657868597265526086
    },
    {
        "price":"1001",
        "sequence":"1636607339565",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"0.01",
        "time":1657868598170110735
    },
    {
        "price":"5689",
        "sequence":"1636607339571",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.00017577",
        "time":1657868599016786169
    },
    {
        "price":"1001",
        "sequence":"1636607339575",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"0.00017577",
        "time":1657868599847374525
    },
    {
        "price":"5689",
        "sequence":"1636607340168",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.01",
        "time":1657869354756776345
    },
    {
        "price":"1001",
        "sequence":"1636607340171",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"0.01",
        "time":1657869355998154084
    },
    {
        "price":"5689",
        "sequence":"1636607340174",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.00017577",
        "time":1657869356825345678
    },
    {
        "price":"1001",
        "sequence":"1636607340180",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"0.00017577",
        "time":1657869357692624956
    },
    {
        "price":"2500",
        "sequence":"1636607341557",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.001",
        "time":1657870618541508945
    },
    {
        "price":"2500",
        "sequence":"1636607341559",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.002",
        "time":1657870618541508945
    },
    {
        "price":"5689",
        "sequence":"1636607341566",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.00017577",
        "time":1657870620769860457
    },
    {
        "price":"1001",
        "sequence":"1636607341569",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"0.000999",
        "time":1657870621674017603
    },
    {
        "price":"1001",
        "sequence":"1636607341647",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"0.07510662",
        "time":1657870777704932538
    },
    {
        "price":"5689",
        "sequence":"1636607341671",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.00527333",
        "time":1657870857711688568
    },
    {
        "price":"5689",
        "sequence":"1636607341674",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.01",
        "time":1657870868834149507
    },
    {
        "price":"1001",
        "sequence":"1636607341677",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"0.01",
        "time":1657870869931861093
    },
    {
        "price":"5689",
        "sequence":"1636607341680",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.00017577",
        "time":1657870870751938985
    },
    {
        "price":"1001",
        "sequence":"1636607341683",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"0.000999",
        "time":1657870871658420024
    },
    {
        "price":"5689",
        "sequence":"1636607341725",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.06474014",
        "time":1657870941440018617
    },
    {
        "price":"1001",
        "sequence":"1636607341743",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"0.06474014",
        "time":1657870960390939598
    },
    {
        "price":"5689",
        "sequence":"1636607341752",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.002",
        "time":1657870973846595055
    },
    {
        "price":"1001",
        "sequence":"1636607341767",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"0.00662687",
        "time":1657871009792192217
    },
    {
        "price":"5689",
        "sequence":"1636607341791",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.004",
        "time":1657871055207222592
    },
    {
        "price":"5689",
        "sequence":"1636607341878",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.06420589",
        "time":1657871246995089433
    },
    {
        "price":"1001",
        "sequence":"1636607341881",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"0.06420589",
        "time":1657871257132151075
    },
    {
        "price":"5011.18714286",
        "sequence":"1636607341907",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.007",
        "time":1657871357664571926
    },
    {
        "price":"1001",
        "sequence":"1636607341911",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"0.007",
        "time":1657871362560748791
    },
    {
        "price":"1001",
        "sequence":"1636607341968",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"0.070073",
        "time":1657871518530117878
    },
    {
        "price":"1001",
        "sequence":"1636607341971",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"0.063382",
        "time":1657871522234372733
    },
    {
        "price":"5689",
        "sequence":"1636607342013",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.01232959",
        "time":1657871675332533829
    },
    {
        "price":"5689",
        "sequence":"1636607342016",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.01115229",
        "time":1657871676052486838
    },
    {
        "price":"5689",
        "sequence":"1636607342022",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.06362616",
        "time":1657871749924575254
    },
    {
        "price":"1001",
        "sequence":"1636607342025",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"0.06362616",
        "time":1657871755000539664
    },
    {
        "price":"2500",
        "sequence":"1636607342521",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.003",
        "time":1657873027819080167
    },
    {
        "price":"5689",
        "sequence":"1636607342636",
        "side":"buy",
        "size":"0.01757778",
        "time":1657873355549703658
    },
    {
        "price":"1001",
        "sequence":"1636607343484",
        "side":"sell",
        "size":"0.89815224",
        "time":1657875048576698842
    }
]}
```

I am trying to read out the values. Unfortunately, this does not work. What I have in mind:

I want to read first ("price" : "200") and then whether it was a sell or buy order ("side" : "sell"). The sell order should then be displayed in a line chart. The same with the buy order.

My Code:

```
import json 

with open('events.json') as f:
json_object = json.load(f)

pairs = json_object.items()

for side, price in pairs:
print(side)
```

Output:

```
code
data

Process finished with exit code 0
```

My Code for the Chart:

```
# importing pandas library
  import pandas as pd
# importing matplotlib library
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# creating dataframe
  df = pd.DataFrame({
  'X': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  'Y': [2, 4, 6, 10, 15]
  })
# plotting a line graph
  print("Line graph: ")
  plt.plot(df["X"], df["Y"])
  plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs a bit more focus. It seems you're trying to draw price lineplots for different values of side. Importing your json to a df is a good starting point. However, you'll notice that the relevant data is found under `data` (which you can access with `json_object['data']`). That should help you starting and narrowing down the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the dictionary data into a dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
df = df['data'].apply(pd.Series)
```

##### Filtering data

```
df_plot = pd.concat([df.loc[df.side.eq('buy'), ['price']].reset_index(drop=True), df.loc[df.side.eq('sell'), ['price']].reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
df_plot.columns = ['buy_price', 'sell_price']
```

##### Line plot

```
df_plot.astype('float').plot.line()
```

[image]

Comment: @jonnyDE glad, I could help you

Answer (score 0):

When you iterate over `pairs` you're actually iterating over keys and values, which in your case is `keys = ["code", "data"]`. I think you want to loop over the data and take `side` and `price` of that list:

```
for item in pairs['data']:
    price = item['price']
    side = item['side']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load data into dataframe from dictionary using.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data["data"])
```

Then, you can just use plotly library to generate the plot directly.

```
import plotly.express as px
px.line(df, y="price", color="side")
```

[image]